# R base graphics change font to Times new roman regular on a Mac

Tags: r

Im following a variation of these https://rpubs.com/thoughtfulbloke/kitegraph instructions and have tried a variety of online suggestions including the library(extrafont) which did not seem to work for me. Any help or pointers in the right direction - I am a novice, much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The *Time* font is the closest to *Times New Roman* I could get, by using `pdf()`:

```
pdf(file="~/Desktop/yourplot.pdf", family="Times")
plot(1:100, 1:100, main="Title")
dev.off()
```

I am not familiar with package `extrafont`, but, according to [this tutorial](https://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2012/09/how-to-use-your-favorite-fonts-in-r-charts.html), it allows to install fonts and to use them by changing the `family=` argument in `pdf()` accordingly.